# IBM MQ get topic name from message in subscription queue

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I am using 'c-client' api to access the `Websphere IBM MQ 8`. Is it possible to identify the source topic from which the message was published ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inquire on the topic string, use the `MQCRTMH` API call to obtain a message handle, then inquire the properties of the message using the `MQINQMP` API call specifying the `MQTopicString` property.

[`MQCRTMH` - Create message handle](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101780_.htm)
[`MQINQMP` - Property Names](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026640_.htm)
[Sample IBM MQ procedural programs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023890_.htm)

Admittedly, it can be difficult to track this info down in the IBM MQ reference documentation, especially if you do not already know the way it works and the names of the calls and fields.  One approach that can help is to start with the sample programs to get a basic understanding and then work back into the manuals to fill in the missing details.  The sample code is available from the install media by selecting the appropriate optional component.

On Windows these end up in `{MQM Home}/Tools` and on UNIX systems at `{MQM Home}/samp`. If the samples are installed, `AMQSIQMA` will demonstrate how to inquire properties of a message handle, and is an example of the use of the `MQINQMP` API call.

Answer (score 2):

> To inquire on the topic string, use the MQCRTMH API call to obtain a
>   message handle, then inquire the properties of the message using the
>   MQINQMP API call specifying the MQTopicString property.

The correct message property name is 'mqps.Top' (case sensitive & no quotes).

Comment: When I run the sample program amqsiqma, the property name output looks like this `property name <MQTopicString> value <X/Y/Z>`, so I think that what T.Rob has is correct.

Comment: On further review both are correct.  Property name `MQTopicString` is the same as MQRFC2 name `mqps.Top`.  The MQINQMP page linked to says `MQINQMP accepts either the property name or MQRFH2 name as the name of the property to inquire on.`